# Sublime text camel humps search

Tags: search, sublime-text-3, intellij-idea

How can I perform "Camel's Hump" search like IDEA (or ReSharper) in sublime text? I mean typing "MLC" and getting suggested to go to MyLittleClass file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text's fuzzy search feature has similar behavior:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to navigate between files
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to navigate in menu
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to navigate between functions, classes etc. in current file

Any of these shortcuts will invoke a list that can be searched using *fuzzy search*. For example you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and start typing any characters that appear in filename, not necessarily in a sequence. All these examples should bring up `MyLittleClass.java`:

- `mlc` (because **M** y **L** ittle **C** lass)
- `mls` (**M** y **L** ittle Cla **s** s)
- `mlt` (**M** y **L** i **t** tle Class)

Of course if you have more files that match that pattern then you may have to type more characters or select appropriate file with keyboard arrows. If you do the latter, Sublime will learn over time and suggest that file for the same search phrase.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> invokes the same feature that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, but enters `@` at the beginning. Then you can jump to notable places in current file, for example `@gin` could take you to `getInstance()`. `@` can be inserted manually to jump to other files: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> `mlc@gin` would bring up `MyLittleClass.java` and jump to `getInstance()`.

Comment: Awesome! And is there way to navigate between code in files, like 'Ctrl+P' and 'Ctrl+R' combined without '@' sign?